# How do I fix this Date class in such a way that date should not be able to change after it's initiated when creating a new Date instance?

Tags: java, arrays, class, instance, return-value

Here follow two pieces of code, and I know that it's not working as intended.
The Date instance is not supposed to be able to change after it's created, but because the `getDate` method returns an array(reference), it's able to change in the second part of my provided code with `int[] dateValue = date.getDate ();`.

I think I'm overthinking this a bit, and need a fresh pair of eyes on the problem.
Am I just supposed to build the `Date`-class with `int y, int m, int d` instead of `int[] ymd` or can I modify the return method and/or add a few more methods to either `Date` or `Problem2`?

Any ideas for how to fix this in the best or easiest way? The class `Problem2` should print out the same thing both times, and/or the `Date`-instance should NOT be changeable!

As for now, I don't even know in what direction I should be thinking.

```
public class Date
{
  private int[] ymd = new int[3];

  public Date (int year, int month, int day)
  {
    ymd[0] = year;
    ymd[1] = month;
    ymd[2] = day;
  }

  public int[] getDate ()
  {
    return ymd;
  }

  public void printDate ()
  {
    System.out.println (ymd[0] + "-" + ymd[1] + "-" + ymd[2]);
  }
}
```

```
public class Problem2
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Date date = new Date (2019, 6, 15);
    date.printDate ();
    int[] dateValue = date.getDate ();
    dateValue[2] = 38;
    date.printDate ();
  }
}
```

As for now, `Problem2` prints out:

```
2019-6-15
2019-6-38
```

When "fixed", it should print the same date both times.

Comment: You can return a clone of the array.

Answer (score 2):

To make the object immutable, you should return a copy of the array in the `getDate()` method.
To do this, you can replace the method by:

```
public int[] getDate ()
{
    return Arrays.copyOf(ymd, ymd.length);
}
```

`Arrays.copyOf` take the array and his length as parameter. The it returns a copy of the array.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) But is there another way, witout using `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: And what type of value is returned if I use this? `Arrays.copyOf`

Comment: @Calle654 it returns the same thing given in parameters but a copy. It that case it will be int[] because ymd is int[] ...

Comment: @Calle654 If you don't want to use `java.util.Arrays`, you can still copy the array by hand. Like that: 
    `public int[] getDate ()
    {
        return new int[]{ymd[0], ymd[1], ymd[2]};
    }`